# Is it possible to install python libraries such as Numpy, Scipy, Pandas and Matplotlib and statsmodels into Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, numpy, pandas, scipy

I'm trying to add these libraries into Eclipse.(Numpy, Scipy, Pandas and Matplotlib and statsmodels) I've already installed python 2.7. If so, can someone tell me how?

Comment: The 2nd answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9657449/python-newbie-importing-numpy-module-in-eclipse explains how to add libraries for use in PyDev in Eclipse.  It is also explained at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675585/how-to-add-python-libraries-to-eclypse-and-pydev.

Comment: One option is to install a distribution of Python that includes all those libraries like Enthought or Anaconda and point your Eclipse at it.

Answer (score 2):

Open the windows command prompt or cmd (not the python prompt)
In the cmd run the command:

```
    pip install numpy 
    pip install pandas
    pip install matplotlib
    pip install scipy
```

Once installed, they are available in eclipse

Answer (score 0):

you just need to add paths where your packages are installed, see the image below

[image]

I hope that helps !